# Docker: unable to start container process: exec: "./pipe": stat ./pipe: no such file or directory: unknown

Tags: docker, go

I'm creating a pipe in golang and trying to use it as pipe in bitbucket-pipelines. I tested the pipe.go file by building it using go build pipe.go which generated a binary called pipe.

I wrote the code in pipe.go file, and the directory structure looks as follows

```
pipe/pipe.go
/pipe.yml
/bitbucket-pipelines.yml
/Dockerfile
```

and I wrote the Dockerfile as follows.

```
# Stage 1: Build the go binary
FROM golang:1.21.6 AS builder

WORKDIR /

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY pipe.yml /
COPY pipe /

# Build the Go application
RUN go build pipe.go

# Stage 2: Create a minimal image for deployment
FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /

# Copy only the necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /pipe .

RUN chmod +x /pipe

RUN ls -l

# Command to run the executable
ENTRYPOINT ["./pipe"]
```

and here are the build logs

```
    Step 1/14 : FROM golang:1.21.6 AS builder
    1.21.6: Pulling from library/golang
    Status: Downloaded newer image for golang:1.21.6
    
    Removing intermediate container 44a6dd748279
    
    Step 8/14 : RUN go build pipe.go
    
    Step 9/14 : FROM alpine:latest
    
    Step 13/14 : RUN ls -l
     ---> Running in 6e942809fe63
    total 7124
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 bin
    drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           340 Feb  1 04:45 dev
    drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb  1 04:45 etc
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 home
    drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 lib
    drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 media
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 mnt
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 opt
    -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       7231614 Feb  1 04:45 pipe
    dr-xr-xr-x  326 nobody   nobody           0 Feb  1 04:45 proc
    drwx------    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 root
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 run
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 sbin
    drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 srv
    dr-xr-xr-x   13 nobody   nobody           0 Feb  1 04:45 sys
    drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 tmp
    drwxr-xr-x    7 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 usr
    drwxr-xr-x   12 root     root          4096 Jan 26 17:53 var
    
    Step 14/14 : ENTRYPOINT ["./pipe"]
```

I can see the pipe binary when I run the `ls -l` command but when I run this image as a container, I'm getting the following error

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./pipe": stat ./pipe: no such file or directory: unknown.
time="2024-02-01T04:47:46Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"

I tried changing ENTRYPOINT command to use ./pipe, /pipe, and CMD but it didn't help.
How do I fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Docker `alpine:1.21.6` is based on Debian (or it could be WindowsServer but yours clearly isn't). A binary built on Debian uses Debian libraries that don't exist on alpine, so you can't run it on alpine. **If you want to run on alpine, build on `:1.21.6-alpine` or as that currently is `-alpine3.19`.**

Comment: How are you running the container? Maybe your workdir is being set to something else when the containers starts?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oh is it? I'll try using the debian base image and see if it helps.

Comment: it got fixed, when I used both base images built on alpine. Thank you @dave_thompson_085

Answer (score 0):

I would move the pipe to `/bin` so it becomes `/bin/pipe` because `/bin/` is in the `$PATH` environment variable. 
When debugging, print out your `$PATH` as well. 
Then just update the entrypoint to point to `/bin/pipe`

What is the command that you start your container with?

Comment: I'll try that, I use it in bitbucket as a pipe, and it runs using the following commands

+ docker container run \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build \
   --volume=/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker:ro \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh:ro \
   --volume=/opt/atlassian/pipes:/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines
   --volume=/opt/atlassianpipe:/opt/atlassian
   --workdir=$(pwd) \
--env=...

standard docker command by setting some volumes and env variables

Comment: running the command RUN echo $PATH gave me the following output

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: it didn't work, now my Dockerfile looks as follows

```
FROM golang:1.21.6 AS builder

WORKDIR /

COPY pipe.yml /
COPY pipe /

RUN go build -o main.o ./pipe.go

RUN ls -l

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=builder /main.o /bin/main.o

RUN chmod +x bin/main.o

RUN ls -l

RUN ls -l bin/main.o

RUN echo $PATH

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/main.o"]
```

Comment: PATH is ignored and irrelevant when command name includes a slash like ./pipe